# Theme looks ugly - FOUC - stylesheets loaded in footer

Tags: css

My theme looks good and it works so far, but in the first seconds of loading the whole layout looks buggy: http://andreapuiatti.de/screenshots/cssstylebug.png

I think is because the css has been loaded with a delay but even positioning the wp_enqueue_style on the top of my functions.php doesn't make any difference

Any Idea on how to fix that?

Follows part of the functions.php

```
// Load Stylesheets
function addMyStyles() {

    wp_register_style('reset', get_template_directory_uri().'/reset.css');
    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', array('reset') );

    wp_enqueue_style('style');

}
add_action('wp_head', 'addMyStyles');

// Load Scripts
if ( !function_exists( 'core_mods' ) ) {
    function core_mods() {
        if ( !is_admin() ) {
            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery', ( "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ), false);
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'core_mods' );
}

function addMyScripts() {
    /*wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/_/js/modernizr.js', null, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr' );*/

    wp_register_script( 'jwplayer', get_template_directory_uri().'/_/js/jwplayer.js', null, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jwplayer' );

    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/_/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' );

    wp_register_script( 'spk_slide', get_template_directory_uri().'/_/js/slides.js', array('jquery'), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'spk_slide' );
}
//add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addMyScripts');

// Add slider to front page
function my_enqueue_stuff() {
  if ( is_front_page() ) {
    addMyScripts();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_stuff' );
```

SOLVED:
after research I found out that that effect name is FOUC (flash of unstyled content). I just had to increase the priority of the function which is adding the stylesheets to get them added to the head section: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'core_mods','2' ).

Comment: Need to see a live example to really pin down this problem. Sounds like your CSS isn't loading in the `<head>` of your site so the content displays, then the CSS is loaded, then the browsers suddenly styles your page.

Comment: You should post that as a proper answer, but the `core_mods` function just hijacks the Core JQuery. I don't see how that alters where the stylesheet loads. Something is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the position of `wp_enqueue_style` inside `functions.php` will make no difference at all. Scripts and styles are printed on a couple of hooks. Placement of the registration functions inside `functions.php` is not a factor.

Your stylesheets are loading in the footer. Neither [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) nor [`wp_register_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) have an `$in_footer` parameter like `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_register-script`.

I have to assume that your theme is loading the scripts manually hooked to `wp_footer`. Look for `add_action('wp_footer',`.

Please edit your question to include the code that includes the stylesheets. That will help with improving this answer.

Comment: no... as you can see I added the stylesheet on wp_head

Comment: and here the header which of course contains the wp_head() call http://jsfiddle.net/QVHSn/

Comment: @AndreaPuiatti : When I look at the source, taken for the address bar in the image you posted, the stylesheets are in the footer. Look down around line 340 in the generated HTML.

Comment: @AndreaPuiatti : I admin that I don't know why the scripts are loading at the bottom. Something odd is happening somewhere in code not posted.

Comment: thank you but that's another website!

Comment: no don't get me wrong, the screenshot is that of the website I'm talking about!

Comment: I checked `http://dev.andreapuiatti.com/dev3/uber-uns/`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is the website I'm working on

Comment: OK. The point stands. The stylesheets are loading at the bottom of the page.

Comment: after a long research I found out that that effect name is FOUC (flash of unstyled content). I just had to increase the priority of the function which is adding the stylesheets to get them added to the head section: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'core_mods','2' ). Thank for your support, I didn't notice that those files were loaded into the footer my bad